# Scrolling text in libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to get text to slowly print one character within a string at a time so the text appears to be printed out and scrolling. I can't seem to find where the answer lies.
Here is what I have tried

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
        e += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(e > 5f){
            System.out.println(e);
            tmp+= text.substring(i, i+1);
            glyph.setText(font, tmp);
            font.draw(batch, glyph, 100 + glyph.width, 100);
            e = 0;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

However the text just zooms off the screen. Any help in accomplishing the smooth one character at a time printing is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the line in the draw call `100 + glyph.width` and it works perfectly